# Cannot retrieve data from provider/reducer when route is manually typed in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am working on a side project of doing en ecommerce store in React. I implemented useContext and useReducer to be able to keep a state of the products that i added in my cart and it's working perfectly as supposed. But if i add a product to my cart and instead of clicking to the cart icon, I change the route manually in the browser to localhost:3000/cart, there's nothing in the cart. I read that typing the URL manually refresh the page and that's the reason i'm loosing the state, but i can't find a way to fix the issue properly.
Do have any ideas ? Thank you !

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Products from './pages/Products/Products';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage/Homepage';
import Contact from './pages/Contact/Contact';
import About from './pages/About/About';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import ProductDetail from './pages/ProductDetail/ProductDetail';
import Cart from './pages/Cart/Cart';
import data from './data.json';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Homepage}/>
        <Route path='/products' render={()=> <Products products={data.products}/>} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
        <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
        <Route path='/productDetail/:id' component={ProductDetail}/>
        <Route path='/cart' component={Cart}/>
      </Switch>
      <Footer/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { StateProvider } from './store.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider>
      <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Store.js

```
import React, {useContext, createContext, useReducer} from 'react';

const StateContext = createContext();
const DispatchContext = createContext();

const reducer = (state,action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
  case 'add product':
    return [...state, action.product];
  case 'remove product': {
    const arr = [...state];
    arr.splice(action.index, 1);
    return arr;
  }
  default:
    throw new Error(`unknown action ${action.type}`);
  }
};

export const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  return(
    <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <StateContext.Provider value={state}>
        {children}
      </StateContext.Provider>
    </DispatchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useCart = () => useContext(StateContext);
export const useDispatch = () => useContext(DispatchContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this would be to store data in localStorage for each reducer state like this

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    let temp;
    switch (action.type) {
      case "add product":
        temp = [...state, action.product];
        localStorage.setItem('cart', temp)
        return ;
      case "remove product": {
        const arr = [...state];
        arr.splice(action.index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('cart', arr)
        return arr;
      }
      default:
        throw new Error(`unknown action ${action.type}`);
    }
  };
```

and use the reducer like this

```
 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, localStorage.getItem("cart") || []);
```

You will have to update the localStorage in every case of all the reducers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there another way to do it without using the local storage ?